# Make it so nginx always has site using https

Tags: nginx

NOTE: example.com is just that. Per the rules of stackoverflow, I'm not using an actual domain.

I've been trying to get it so my nginx server for a single site always uses https.

I have the certificate installed and if I view the site with:

https://www.example.com it works fine.

But by default it goes to http and shows the site as insecure.

Here is the config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/nodeapp;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        location / {
          proxy_pass https://[IP address here]:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I esentially want everything to point to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Because your site has both of http and https. (80 port and 443 port).
To activate the only `https` you have to remove the config for http.
Please remove `listen 80` and use `listen 443` instead.
If you want to redirect all traffics to `https`,
you could add redirection config as following.

```
server{
    if ($host = your_domain) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name  your_domain;
    listen 80;
    return 404; 
}
```

I've assumed that your config has `ssl` part in your main config.
For example,

```
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/***/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/**/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/**/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```